# Call a function when anywhere except the symbol is clicked?

Tags: flash, actionscript, mouseevent, event-listener

How can I make it so a function is called when anywhere except a certain symbol is clicked. For example, let's say I have an instance of a symbol called mySymbol.
If I wanted a function named myFunction, to be called when the symbol is clicked I would do it like this:

```
mySymbol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);
function myFunction (evt:MouseEvent) {
code here
}
```

But what if I wanted code to activate when I clicked anywhere except the symbol? If I try to use `stage.addEventListener`, the `eventlisteners` overlap.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Events are bubbling from the symbol up to the stage, so, you have to 
add click event listener to stage (this will catch all the bubbling clicks from all the display objects), and then stop event bubbling in a symbol's click handler:

```
mySymbol.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);
stage.addEventListener(MouseClick.CLICK, onStageClick);

function onStageClick (evt:MouseEvent) {
  trace("clicked somewhere!");
}

function myFunction (evt:MouseEvent) {
  trace("clicked on my symbol, stopping propagation!");
  evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

now, when you click anywhere but in your symbol, it will trace "clicked somewhere!", and clicking on a symbol will produce "clicked on my symbol, stopping propagation!". Without `stopImmediatePropagation` line
it will say:

"clicked on my symbol, stopping propagation!"

"clicked somewhere!"

which is not what you want.

see documentation for event http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29

also find some time to read about overall events behaviour in a flash player: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee9.html

Another way to do this (without stopping event propagation), is to just check whether event's target is your symbol (or is contained in your symbol) inside the stage click handler:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStageClick);

function onStageClick(event:MouseEvent) {
  if (!shouldIgnoreEventTarget(event.target as DisplayObject)) {
    trace("clicked somewhere!");
  }
}

function shouldIgnoreEventTarget(target:DisplayObject):Boolean {
  if (!target) {
    return false;
  }

  if (target == mySymbol) {
    return true;
  }

  if (mySymbol is DisplayObjectContainer &&
      DisplayObjectContainer(mySymbol).contains(target)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```